# php/ajax random characters and countdown

Tags: php, ajax, actionscript-3, random, countdown

I'm trying to simulate The words game in as3.
The same random characters or all users and 2 minutes countdown is needed

I've a code That generate 25 random characters. How Can I Show The Random Characters For all Users ?

```
<?PHP
     function randStr($rts=20) { 
     $act_chars = "ABCÇADAEFGĞHEIİJKELMNOAÖPRKSŞTUÜVYZ"; 
     $act_val = ""; 
     for($act=0; $act <$rts ; $act++) { 
       mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
       $act_val .= mb_substr($act_chars, mt_rand(0, mb_strlen($act_chars)-1), 1);
     } 

     return $act_val; 
    } 
    $dene = randStr(25);
    print "izinliharfler=$dene";
?>
```

maybe I need to use cron job, I do not know

Answer (score 0):

You Can Store The Generated string (Characters String) In A Table,

Then Create An ajax call To Pull It For All Users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ip address of the user and then change seed accordingly.

```
<?PHP
     function randStr($rts=20,$ip) { 
     $act_chars = "ABCÇADAEFGĞHEIİJKELMNOAÖPRKSŞTUÜVYZ"; 
     $act_val = ""; 
     for($act=0; $act <$rts ; $act++) { 
       mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000+$ip); 
       $act_val .= mb_substr($act_chars, mt_rand(0, mb_strlen($act_chars)-1), 1);
     } 

     return $act_val; 
    }
    $ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $dene = randStr(25,$ip);
    print "izinliharfler=$dene";
?>
```